# Regression: operands could not be broadcast together with shapes

Tags: python, pandas, statistics, logistic-regression, statsmodels

I've been trying to make a logistic regression, but I keep getting an error. Here's the code I'm using. I'm at a loss.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from sklearn import preprocessing
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt 
plt.rc("font", size=14)
from sklearn.linear_model import LogisticRegression
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
import seaborn as sns
sns.set(style="white")
sns.set(style="whitegrid", color_codes=True)
data = pd.read_excel('regression.xlsx', header=0)
data = data.dropna()
dataD = pd.get_dummies(data)
print(dataD.shape)
print(list(dataD.columns))
dataD.head()
X = dataD.loc[:, dataD.columns != 'y']
y = dataD.loc[:, dataD.columns == 'y']
```

This is the output:

```
(12805, 31)
['Start PHQ-9', 'Start GAD-7', 'Start WSAS', 'Treatment Sessions', 'Improvement', 'Cognitive Reattribution', 'Behavioural Reattribution', 'Psychoeducation', 'Conceputalisation', 'Skill Teaching', 'Therapeutic Empathy', 'Therapeutic Praise', 'Gender_F', 'Gender_M', 'Gender_Z', 'Ethnicity_U/Z', 'Ethnicity_White', 'Ethnicity_other', 'Employment Status_Employed', 'Employment Status_Other', 'Employment Status_U/Z', 'Employment Status_Unemployed', 'Age Group_18-25', 'Age Group_26-35', 'Age Group_36-45', 'Age Group_46-55', 'Age Group_56-65', 'Age Group_66+', 'Medication Status_Not Prescribed', 'Medication Status_Prescribed Not Taking', 'Medication Status_Prescribed Taking']
```

But then when I try to execute the logistic regression:

```
import statsmodels.api as sm
logit_model=sm.Logit(y,X)
result=logit_model.fit()
print(result.summary2())
```

I get this error:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
Input In [3], in <cell line: 3>()
      1 import statsmodels.api as sm
      2 logit_model=sm.Logit(y,X)
----> 3 result=logit_model.fit()
      4 print(result.summary2())

File /opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/statsmodels/discrete/discrete_model.py:1983, in Logit.fit(self, start_params, method, maxiter, full_output, disp, callback, **kwargs)
   1980 @Appender(DiscreteModel.fit.__doc__)
   1981 def fit(self, start_params=None, method='newton', maxiter=35,
   1982         full_output=1, disp=1, callback=None, **kwargs):
-> 1983     bnryfit = super().fit(start_params=start_params,
   1984                           method=method,
   1985                           maxiter=maxiter,
   1986                           full_output=full_output,
   1987                           disp=disp,
   1988                           callback=callback,
   1989                           **kwargs)
   1991     discretefit = LogitResults(self, bnryfit)
   1992     return BinaryResultsWrapper(discretefit)

File /opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/statsmodels/discrete/discrete_model.py:230, in DiscreteModel.fit(self, start_params, method, maxiter, full_output, disp, callback, **kwargs)
    227 else:
    228     pass  # TODO: make a function factory to have multiple call-backs
--> 230 mlefit = super().fit(start_params=start_params,
    231                      method=method,
    232                      maxiter=maxiter,
    233                      full_output=full_output,
    234                      disp=disp,
    235                      callback=callback,
    236                      **kwargs)
    238 return mlefit

File /opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/statsmodels/base/model.py:563, in LikelihoodModel.fit(self, start_params, method, maxiter, full_output, disp, fargs, callback, retall, skip_hessian, **kwargs)
    560     del kwargs["use_t"]
    562 optimizer = Optimizer()
--> 563 xopt, retvals, optim_settings = optimizer._fit(f, score, start_params,
    564                                                fargs, kwargs,
    565                                                hessian=hess,
    566                                                method=method,
    567                                                disp=disp,
    568                                                maxiter=maxiter,
    569                                                callback=callback,
    570                                                retall=retall,
    571                                                full_output=full_output)
    572 # Restore cov_type, cov_kwds and use_t
    573 optim_settings.update(kwds)

File /opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/statsmodels/base/optimizer.py:241, in Optimizer._fit(self, objective, gradient, start_params, fargs, kwargs, hessian, method, maxiter, full_output, disp, callback, retall)
    238     fit_funcs.update(extra_fit_funcs)
    240 func = fit_funcs[method]
--> 241 xopt, retvals = func(objective, gradient, start_params, fargs, kwargs,
    242                      disp=disp, maxiter=maxiter, callback=callback,
    243                      retall=retall, full_output=full_output,
    244                      hess=hessian)
    246 optim_settings = {'optimizer': method, 'start_params': start_params,
    247                   'maxiter': maxiter, 'full_output': full_output,
    248                   'disp': disp, 'fargs': fargs, 'callback': callback,
    249                   'retall': retall, "extra_fit_funcs": extra_fit_funcs}
    250 optim_settings.update(kwargs)

File /opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/statsmodels/base/optimizer.py:439, in _fit_newton(f, score, start_params, fargs, kwargs, disp, maxiter, callback, retall, full_output, hess, ridge_factor)
    437     H[np.diag_indices(H.shape[0])] += ridge_factor
    438 oldparams = newparams
--> 439 newparams = oldparams - np.linalg.solve(H, score(oldparams))
    440 if retall:
    441     history.append(newparams)

File /opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/statsmodels/base/model.py:536, in LikelihoodModel.fit.<locals>.score(params, *args)
    535 def score(params, *args):
--> 536     return self.score(params, *args) / nobs

File /opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/statsmodels/discrete/discrete_model.py:1928, in Logit.score(self, params)
   1926 X = self.exog
   1927 L = self.cdf(np.dot(X,params))
-> 1928 return np.dot(y - L,X)

ValueError: operands could not be broadcast together with shapes (12805,0) (12805,) 

import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from sklearn import preprocessing
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt 
plt.rc("font", size=14)
from sklearn.linear_model import LogisticRegression
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
import seaborn as sns
sns.set(style="white")
sns.set(style="whitegrid", color_codes=True)
data = pd.read_excel('regression.xlsx', header=0)
data = data.dropna()
dataD = pd.get_dummies(data)
print(dataD.shape)
print(list(dataD.columns))
dataD.head()
X = dataD.loc[:, dataD.columns != 'y']
y = dataD.loc[:, dataD.columns == 'y']
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from sklearn import preprocessing
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt 
plt.rc("font", size=14)
from sklearn.linear_model import LogisticRegression
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
import seaborn as sns
sns.set(style="white")
sns.set(style="whitegrid", color_codes=True)
data = pd.read_excel('regression.xlsx', header=0)
data = data.dropna()
dataD = pd.get_dummies(data)
print(dataD.shape)
print(list(dataD.columns))
dataD.head()
X = dataD.loc[:, dataD.columns != 'y']
y = dataD.loc[:, dataD.columns == 'y']
(12805, 31)
['Start PHQ-9', 'Start GAD-7', 'Start WSAS', 'Treatment Sessions', 'Improvement', 'Cognitive Reattribution', 'Behavioural Reattribution', 'Psychoeducation', 'Conceputalisation', 'Skill Teaching', 'Therapeutic Empathy', 'Therapeutic Praise', 'Gender_F', 'Gender_M', 'Gender_Z', 'Ethnicity_U/Z', 'Ethnicity_White', 'Ethnicity_other', 'Employment Status_Employed', 'Employment Status_Other', 'Employment Status_U/Z', 'Employment Status_Unemployed', 'Age Group_18-25', 'Age Group_26-35', 'Age Group_36-45', 'Age Group_46-55', 'Age Group_56-65', 'Age Group_66+', 'Medication Status_Not Prescribed', 'Medication Status_Prescribed Not Taking', 'Medication Status_Prescribed Taking']
import statsmodels.api as sm
logit_model=sm.Logit(y,X)
result=logit_model.fit()
print(result.summary2())
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
Input In [5], in <cell line: 3>()
      1 import statsmodels.api as sm
      2 logit_model=sm.Logit(y,X)
----> 3 result=logit_model.fit()
      4 print(result.summary2())

File /opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/statsmodels/discrete/discrete_model.py:1983, in Logit.fit(self, start_params, method, maxiter, full_output, disp, callback, **kwargs)
   1980 @Appender(DiscreteModel.fit.__doc__)
   1981 def fit(self, start_params=None, method='newton', maxiter=35,
   1982         full_output=1, disp=1, callback=None, **kwargs):
-> 1983     bnryfit = super().fit(start_params=start_params,
   1984                           method=method,
   1985                           maxiter=maxiter,
   1986                           full_output=full_output,
   1987                           disp=disp,
   1988                           callback=callback,
   1989                           **kwargs)
   1991     discretefit = LogitResults(self, bnryfit)
   1992     return BinaryResultsWrapper(discretefit)

File /opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/statsmodels/discrete/discrete_model.py:230, in DiscreteModel.fit(self, start_params, method, maxiter, full_output, disp, callback, **kwargs)
    227 else:
    228     pass  # TODO: make a function factory to have multiple call-backs
--> 230 mlefit = super().fit(start_params=start_params,
    231                      method=method,
    232                      maxiter=maxiter,
    233                      full_output=full_output,
    234                      disp=disp,
    235                      callback=callback,
    236                      **kwargs)
    238 return mlefit

File /opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/statsmodels/base/model.py:563, in LikelihoodModel.fit(self, start_params, method, maxiter, full_output, disp, fargs, callback, retall, skip_hessian, **kwargs)
    560     del kwargs["use_t"]
    562 optimizer = Optimizer()
--> 563 xopt, retvals, optim_settings = optimizer._fit(f, score, start_params,
    564                                                fargs, kwargs,
    565                                                hessian=hess,
    566                                                method=method,
    567                                                disp=disp,
    568                                                maxiter=maxiter,
    569                                                callback=callback,
    570                                                retall=retall,
    571                                                full_output=full_output)
    572 # Restore cov_type, cov_kwds and use_t
    573 optim_settings.update(kwds)

File /opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/statsmodels/base/optimizer.py:241, in Optimizer._fit(self, objective, gradient, start_params, fargs, kwargs, hessian, method, maxiter, full_output, disp, callback, retall)
    238     fit_funcs.update(extra_fit_funcs)
    240 func = fit_funcs[method]
--> 241 xopt, retvals = func(objective, gradient, start_params, fargs, kwargs,
    242                      disp=disp, maxiter=maxiter, callback=callback,
    243                      retall=retall, full_output=full_output,
    244                      hess=hessian)
    246 optim_settings = {'optimizer': method, 'start_params': start_params,
    247                   'maxiter': maxiter, 'full_output': full_output,
    248                   'disp': disp, 'fargs': fargs, 'callback': callback,
    249                   'retall': retall, "extra_fit_funcs": extra_fit_funcs}
    250 optim_settings.update(kwargs)

File /opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/statsmodels/base/optimizer.py:439, in _fit_newton(f, score, start_params, fargs, kwargs, disp, maxiter, callback, retall, full_output, hess, ridge_factor)
    437     H[np.diag_indices(H.shape[0])] += ridge_factor
    438 oldparams = newparams
--> 439 newparams = oldparams - np.linalg.solve(H, score(oldparams))
    440 if retall:
    441     history.append(newparams)

File /opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/statsmodels/base/model.py:536, in LikelihoodModel.fit.<locals>.score(params, *args)
    535 def score(params, *args):
--> 536     return self.score(params, *args) / nobs

File /opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/statsmodels/discrete/discrete_model.py:1928, in Logit.score(self, params)
   1926 X = self.exog
   1927 L = self.cdf(np.dot(X,params))
-> 1928 return np.dot(y - L,X)

ValueError: operands could not be broadcast together with shapes (12805,0) (12805,)
```

I'd really appreciate any help I can get. Thank you.

Comment: Try converting `y`  to a pandas Series. It looks like it is a one column DataFrame which does not seem to be converted to a 1-dim array inside the model.

Comment: @Josef I used y=y.squeeze() but I still get the same error. Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: check np.asarray(y).ndim which should be 1. The ValueError `(12805,0)` looks like y is 2-dim but with no columns.  Do you really have a column with name `'y'` in `dataD` ?

Comment: @Josef I checked it is actually 1. But no, I don't have a column named y in dataD... I'm so close to smashing my keyboard man loool